# How to find out how many datasets each package contains in R?

Tags: r, package, dataset

Please help me with a command which will return number of datasets in a package, eg.package = "MASS". I tried data(package = "MASS") but it returns me a list. However I want to know the number of datasets in the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

```
nrow(data(package = "MASS")$result)
#[1] 87
```

Long answer: `data(package = "MASS")` returns an object of class `packageIQR` which has a nice `print` method that let you see all the available datasets. However, that object is actually a `list` and the `result` component is a `matrix` with a row for each dataset containing location, name and description. Using `nrow` on it you get the number of datasets.

```
a <- data(package = "MASS")
str(a)
#List of 4
# $ title  : chr "Data sets"
# $ header : NULL
# $ results: chr [1:87, 1:4] "MASS" "MASS" "MASS" "MASS" ...
#  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  .. ..$ : NULL
#  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Package" "LibPath" "Item" "Title"
# $ footer : NULL
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "packageIQR"tr(a)
head(a$results[,3:4])
#     Item       Title                                                 
#[1,] "Aids2"    "Australian AIDS Survival Data"                       
#[2,] "Animals"  "Brain and Body Weights for 28 Species"               
#[3,] "Boston"   "Housing Values in Suburbs of Boston"                 
#[4,] "Cars93"   "Data from 93 Cars on Sale in the USA in 1993"        
#[5,] "Cushings" "Diagnostic Tests on Patients with Cushing's Syndrome"
#[6,] "DDT"      "DDT in Kale"

nrow(a$result)
#[1] 87
```